# convert a dataframe to vector

Tags: dataframe, vector

I have a dataframe named tickers as follows

```
tickers <- data.frame(
  country = c("Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Denmark", "Finland", "France", "Germany"),
  ticker = c("SBADL Index", "SBASL Index", "SBBFL Index", "SBCDL Index", "SBDKL Index", "SBFML Index", "SBFFL Index", "SBDML Index"),
  name = NA,
  currency = NA,
  hedged = NA,
  inception = NA
)
```

I am performing the following operations on tickers

```
securities=tickers$ticker%>%setNames(tickers$country)
```

and getting the output as

```
   Australia          Austria          Belgium           Canada          Denmark          Finland           France          Germany 
   "SBADL Index"    "SBASL Index"    "SBBFL Index"    "SBCDL Index"    "SBDKL Index"    "SBFML Index"    "SBFFL Index"    "SBDML Index" 
          Greece        Hong Kong          Ireland            Italy            Japan      Netherlands      New Zealand           Norway 
   "SBGRL Index" "I28692HK Index" "LETITREU Index"    "SBITL Index"    "SBJYL Index"    "SBDGL Index" "I00726NZ Index" "I00727NO Index" 
        Portugal        Singapore            Spain           Sweden      Switzerland               UK               US         Eurozone 
   "SBPEL Index"    "SBSGL Index"    "SBSPL Index"    "SBSKL Index"    "SBSZL Index"    "SBUKL Index" "LUATTRUU Index" "LEATTREU Index"
```

How should I convert the output to a vector equal to c( SBADL_Index , SBASL_Index , ...)
?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to be a straight character vector, you can use `tickers$ticker`. `df$colname` is the general way of getting columns as vectors with base R, replacing df and colname with the name of your dataframe and column name respectively. With dplyr, you can use `df |> dplyr::pull(colname)`.

```
> tickers$ticker
[1] "SBADL Index" "SBASL Index" "SBBFL Index" "SBCDL Index" "SBDKL Index"
[6] "SBFML Index" "SBFFL Index" "SBDML Index"
```